# Custom 404 page in a theme doesn't work as expected,

Tags: theming

I want to use a custom 404 page, I also have a theme installed.

This is what I did:

1. Go to Content, create a Node, I got path: node/28
2. Go to System->Site Information->Error Pages-> 404 page, I enter node/28

Then I type some pages that are not exists, it doesn't link me to the `node/28`, instead, it still use the themes' 404 page.

Some hint here?

BTW, I am using Drupal 7 and the theme called MD magnum.

Comment: Did you try clearning cache? If not use drush to do so: drush cc all

Comment: does your theme already have an error page template?

Comment: @CR47  Hi,thanks, I clear the cache, and it works, but not correctly, the themes' 404 page overlap with my node/28. I only want to show my own 404 page, so what should I do to disable the themes' 404 page?

Comment: @jdu Hi,thanks, I clear the cache, and it works, but not correctly, the themes' 404 page overlap with my node/28. I only want to show my own 404 page, so what should I do to disable the themes' 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

Do what @jdu said and check the theme's template files for an error page template.  It will probably have the name page--error.tpl.php and probably be in /sites/all/themes/md_magnum/templates/

After that set your new error page URL in admin/config/site-information to the node you created.

To verify it is set you can check in your database under the variables table for site_404 to be set to that URL.

Make sure after you make these changes you clear cache completely and refresh your page.  If you are in Chrome, you may have to clear browser cache as well if you are using the same URL.